# Multiple PHP Function handlers in HTML Form?

Tags: php, html, forms, octobercms

I'm using [OctoberCMS](http://octobercms.com/) based on [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) and [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/).

I'm trying to call 2 different functions form 2 php files using 1 form and 2 submit buttons.

[image: form]

I connect components I made, `Edit.php` and `Delete.php`, to a page.

Instead of directing the Form action to /Edit.php, I direct it to the current url and use a handler to call the php function `onEdit()` in `Edit.php`, using the Edit submit button.

In the same form, how can I call `onDelete()` in `Delete.php` using the Delete submit button?

It only selects 1 handler and calls its function.

I cannot merge the two functions into 1 php file.

https://jsfiddle.net/t3t5e2Ln/

Form

```
<!-- Edit or Delete -->
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_current() }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <!-- Edit Handler -->
    <input type="hidden" name="_handler" value="onEdit" />

    <!-- Delete Handler -->
    <input type="hidden" name="_handler2" value="onDelete" /> 

    <!-- Title -->
    <input type="text" name="title" maxlength="255" />

    <!-- Edit Submit -->
    <input type="submit" name="edit" value="Edit" />

    <!-- Delete Submit -->
    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" />

</form>
```

Edit.php

```
public function onEdit() {
    //edit
}
```

Delete.php

```
public function onDelete() {
    //delete
}
```

Comment: Just use two forms? This is an unnecessary complicated solution to something very simple. Two forms, and if need be, style them appropriately to keep the look you want.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie I'm using two forms right now to get around this poblem, but the way my layout is set up, I'm not able to position the two submit buttons next to each other using css.

Comment: Why? There is absolutely nothing preventing you to rearrange those submit-buttons however you want, regardless of layout. But yeah, it's never smart to have two submit-buttons in the same form regardless, unless you take precautions for what happens if a user presses "Enter" in the form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both previous answers are incorrect. See http://octobercms.com/docs/cms/components and http://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/components for more information on developing custom components for October.

First off, I would put both handlers within the same component (RecordData.php as an example of a name). Secondly, you should be taking advantage of October's excellent AJAX framework: http://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/introduction.

Here's an example of what your RecordData.php component class could look like:

```
<?php namespace MyVendor\MyPlugin\Components;

use Auth;
use Flash;
use Cms\Classes\ComponentBase;

use MyVendor\MyPlugin\Models\MyRecord as MyRecordModel;

class RecordData extends ComponentBase
{    
    /**
     * Provide information about the component
     */
    public function componentDetails()
    {
        return [
            'name'        => 'RecordData Component',
            'description' => 'Used for editing and deleting custom record data'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Register any component properties
     * http://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/components#component-properties
     */
    public function defineProperties()
    {
        // return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get the record that will be edited, factoring in the user's access to the specified record
     *
     * @return MyRecordModel
     */
    public function getRecord()
    {    
        $user = Auth::getUser();

        if ($user) {
            return MyRecordModel::findOrFail(post('recordId'));
        } else {
            throw new \Exception("You do not have access to do that.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * AJAX Handler for editing data
     */
    public function onEdit()
    {
        // Get the record
        $record = $this->getRecord();

        // Modify the record
        $record->title = post('title');

        // Save the modifications to the record
        $record->save();

        // Notify the user that the record has been edited
        Flash::success("Record successfully edited");
    }

    /**
     * AJAX Handler for deleting data
     */
    public function onDelete()
    {
        // Get the record
        $record = $this->getRecord();

        // Delete the record
        $record->delete();

        // Notify the user that the record has been deleted
        Flash::success("Record deleted");
    }
}
```

And then your `default.htm` partial to render that component would look like this:

```
{{ form_open() }}

    {# Hidden form field containing the record id. Passing the record id through the URL or other means is possible as well #}
    <input type="hidden" name="recordId" value="{{ __SELF__.recordId }}">

    {# Title #}
    <input type="text" name="title" maxlength="255" />

    {# Edit Button #}
    <button type="button" data-request="{{ __SELF__ }}::onEdit">Save changes</button>

    {# Delete Button #}
    <button type="button" data-request="{{ __SELF__ }}::onDelete">Delete record</button>

{{ form_close() }}
```

Let me walk you through the Twig markup that is pasted above:

[`{{ form_open() }}` and `{{ form_close() }}`](https://octobercms.com/docs/markup/function-form) are Twig helper functions registered by October to simplify the act of creating form elements because they will automatically make sure that the correct markup is generated and it includes the csrf token hidden field if you choose to enable that on your site.

`{# #}` represent a comment block in Twig, I usually prefer to use them instead of `<!-- -->` because that way the comment will only be visible to people viewing the actual source code of the Twig file, not all your website's users.

`data-request` utilizes the [attributes API](http://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/attributes-api) of the October AJAX framework to indicate to the AJAX framework what method on the server will be responsible for handling requests triggered by the element that the `data-request` attribute is included on.

`{{ __SELF__ }}` refers to the current component, it will essentially drop in the value of that component's alias. Basically, all you need to know is that using it will enable to you put more than one component on the page at a time in the future. `::onDelete` and `::onEdit` after the `{{ __SELF__ }}` is what tells the server what method you want to run on the component specified by `{{ __SELF__ }}` to handle that AJAX request.

Comment: Very good information. Allow me to take some time to go through this and get back to you.

Comment: I included the Twig form markup on my Page I'm getting Error: Unknown "form_open" tag. What helper do I include and where do I put it, in the 'Code' section?

Comment: I think there is a typo in your markup, it's {{ instead of {% I noticed in the documentation.

Comment: Good catch, thanks! I'm sometimes prone to mixing those up when writing pseudo code :)

Comment: I'm trying to test it on a smaller form before doing the 2 functions. On this form you enter the record name in a textbox and press delete. But the form will not submit when data-request is added to the input button, it just stays on the same page. It works without using twig. Here is the code http://kopy.io/HL0jm

Comment: I have included AJAX {{ framework extras }} and {{ script }}. I've noticed there is a form_ajax() instead of form_open, I havent tried yet.

Comment: Are you sure the form isn't submitting? AJAX requests are made without navigating away from the page. You don't even need your button to be `type=submit`. Check your network tab of your developer tools to see if the request is being made. By default, that request would be made and the action take, but nothing would be displayed to the user because you haven't told the AJAX framework to handle flash requests and you haven't told the framework to do anything after making the request either.

Comment: It does not submit or flash message. It does submit if I use form_ajax('onDelete'), but I need the functions on the buttons. Here's a simplified code example of what I'm using. http://kopy.io/iDCEm

Comment: I got it to work using data-request="onDelete" without SELF. Now 2 submit buttons work in 1 form. I'm going to submit another question about how to call 2 functions at the same time using this ajax form, I'll post a link.

Comment: Here is my extended question http://stackoverflow.com/q/42715977/6806643

Comment: Added my extend answer. By the way, the `__SELF__` is used if you are building this within a component. If you are just building it within a CMS page or layout, then you wouldn't use the `__SELF__` variable to clarify which component will contain the method.

Answer (score 2):

Usually this should be done by ajax request, so you can choose the endpoint independently, but use a few js can do the trick also.

```
$('input[type=submit]').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var url = '/Edit.php';
   if (this.name == 'delete') {
        url = '/Delete.php';
   }
   this.form.action = url;
   this.form.submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in your header

```
<head>
<script language="javascript" src="editordelete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

your buttons

```
<input type="button" name="edit" value=edit  onClick="seteditAction();" />
<input type="button" name="edit" value=edit  onClick="setdeleteAction();" />
```

create a file called "editordelete.js and put this inside put your form name where i wrote yourformnamesgoeshere

```
function seteditAction() {
document.yourformnamegoeshere.action = "Edit.php";
document.yourformnamegoeshere.submit();
}
function setdeleteAction() {
document.yourformnamegoeshere.action = "Delete.php";
document.yourformnamegoeshere.submit();

}
```

give your form a name ,method is post and action is noting

```
<form name="yourformnamegoeshere" method="post" action="">
```