# How to call 2 Functions at the same time using Twig AJAX Form?

Tags: php, ajax, twig, octobercms

I'm using [OctoberCMS](https://octobercms.com/) based on [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) and [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/).

I'm using a [Twig AJAX Form](https://octobercms.com/docs/markup/function-form) that has 2 buttons. Each call a PHP function, `actionOne()` and `actionTwo()`.

How do I make the second button call both functions at the same time?

Using multiple `data-request` on a button doesn't work. And using multiple functions separated by comma in `data-request` also doesn't work.

Form

```
{{ form_open() }}

    <button type="button" data-request="actionOne">Action 1</button>
    <button type="button" data-request="actionTwo">Action 1 & 2</button>

    <input type="checkbox" name="queuedOne[]" value="{{ record.one }}" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="queuedTwo[]" value="{{ record.two }}" />

{{ form_close() }}
```

Edit: I have corrected the values of data-request and name.

Comment: `$('button[data-request="actionTwo"]').on('click', function() { $('button[data-request="actionOne"]').trigger('click'); }` should work

Comment: @DarkBee It does not seem to work, only function actionOne is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways you could accomplish this.

First option, you could create a third PHP method that simply does both of the things that you want to accomplish and then call that instead:

```
function onActionThree() {
    onActionOne();
    onActionTwo();
}
```

and

```
<button data-request="actionThree">Click me for both previous actions</button>
```

Second option, you could utilize the [AJAX Framework JS API](http://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/javascript-api) to make two separate AJAX requests to `actionOne` and `actionTwo`.

```
<button id="action-three-btn">Click me for both previous actions</button>

<script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
       $('#action-three-btn').on('click', function (e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           $(this).request('actionOne');
           $(this).request('actionTwo');
       });
   });
</script>
```

I'll leave this off with a final comment, please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem and http://xyproblem.info/. This vague abstraction of your questions isn't helping anyone actually address your real problem.

Comment: I was able to use the API to make two requests. I have broken down a large project into small problems. Each feature works on its own, but adds more functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know this CMS but If you can write own js code. Then use this

```js
$('document').ready(function(){

    function onOne(){

        here your function

    };

    function actionTwo(){

        here your function

    };


    $("#BUTTONNAME").on('click mouseenter keyup keypress',function(){

        onOne();
        actionTwo();

    });

});
```

Also I give u an advice, all this CMS stuff out there make the Programming not easier. Wrote your own Stuff an then you dont have this problems.

Hope it help

Comment: Your last comment does not make any sense. Not point in reinventing the wheel every time.

Comment: I should have been more specific. It is calling php functions.

Comment: Ok now i understand. Why u called the "Action 1" function in "Action 2" function too? or make a Action 3 function and in that u called Action1 & Action 2, in btn call u Action 3.